# Facebook share image sharedialog

Tags: java, android, facebook, api

I'm sharing an image with my app, and the code is this:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(Show.this)
                            .setDescription("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx!")
                            .setApplicationName("appname")
                            .setPlace("me/photos/")
                            .setPicture(imagesURL+imageFileName)
                            .setLink("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=x.x.xxx")
                            .build();
```

everything is fine, but the image is getting shared small-sized on the side of the link, and not into the user's profile, what should i do to share it like a normal "big" photo?

Also, if i take the

```
.setLink(xxxxxxxxxxxx);
```

the image isn't shared at all..

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that in your setLink() function you are giving the link of the page not the image resource.

For example if you have an image link like this .
http://blog.delicious.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/facebook_logo.jpg

now as this is the link to the image resource on the server, If you use it in the setlink function

```
setLink("http://blog.delicious.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/facebook_logo.jpg");
```

You will get the big Image.

Comment: i'm not very familiar with the facebook api, but i thought the link was a thing and the picture was another.. i wanted to connect the link to my app on the play store, and the image to an image on my server. You're saying in the setLink(); i have to put the image url?

Comment: Yes if You want to get the big image then you have to set the link of the image . If you can give me the link You are using hopefully I can help You more. Thanks

Comment: i've tried that just now, but it simply puts the image as link, i've even tried with an image from a casual website and it acts exactly like that.. i wanted to do something like: big image shared from the smartphone or my server and then down under that image, a link to the playstore. Unfortunately i cannot share the url of my webserver

Comment: You can't share on facebook like what you want. You have to follow the facebook convention for an image or link to share.

Comment: i've found out there's a FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder, and there's a method called .addPhotoFiles, do you know how to use that? I wanna try use this instead on the previous one and see if this works

Comment: Here You can see many different functions for what You want .
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder/

I think this function can help You.
addImageAttachments();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50793/discussion-between-farhangdon-and-domewtf)

Comment: @farhangdon can we know what happened in chat? I think this may be helpful to everyone!